# Multiple values in query

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am trying to get stats for categories, where I want to specify multiple categories. I have query params like this

```
$query_params = json_decode('{
          "aggregated_by": "day", 
          "limit": 500,
          "categories": "category1 category2",
          "start_date": "2018-08-12", 
          "end_date": "2018-08-13"}');
```

Obviously the way that I am defining multiple categories is wrong, but what is the correct way ? I tried array, comma/space separated values but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just name [each category in a distinct argument](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Stats/categories.html). In your example, It'd probably look like:

`$query_params = json_decode('{
          "aggregated_by": "day", 
          "limit": 500,
          "categories": "category1",
          "categories": "category2",
          "start_date": "2018-08-12", 
          "end_date": "2018-08-13"}');`

Comment: I could swear that It worked, but now It looks like it return STDObject which have only the latest categories parameter, all categories parameters before the last one are ignored

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this by passing the parameters as array:

```
$query = array('categories' => ['cat1','cat2']);
```

And then I modified sendgrid client buildUrl method like this:

```
private function buildUrl($queryParams = null)
    {
        $path = '/' . implode('/', $this->path);
        if (isset($queryParams)) {
            $queryParams = \http_build_query($queryParams);
            $path .= '?' . preg_replace('/%5B(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)%5D=/', '=', $queryParams);
        }
        return sprintf('%s%s%s', $this->host, $this->version ?: '', $path);
    }
```

I added the `preg_replace` part so the url is correctly built without including array key  from nested array.